# Parser for Quoted string using Parsec

Tags: parsing, haskell, parsec

I want to parse input strings like this: `"this is \"test \" message \"sample\" text"`

Now, I wrote a parser for parsing individual text without any quotes:

```
parseString :: Parser String
parseString = do
  char '"'
  x <- (many $ noneOf "\"")
  char '"'
  return x
```

This parses simple strings like this: `"test message"`

Then I wrote a parser for quoted strings:

```
quotedString :: Parser String
quotedString = do
  initial <- string "\\\""
  x <- many $ noneOf "\\\"" 
  end <- string "\\\""
  return $ initial ++ x ++ end
```

This parsers for strings like this: `\"test message\"`

Is there a way that I can combine both the parsers so that I obtain my desired objective ? What exactly is the idomatic way to tackle this problem ?

Comment: Why do you want to strip the initial and final quotation marks, but leave the escaping backslashes intact? I would think you'd want to parse the input `"\"ab\\\"c\""` as either `"\"ab\\\"c\""` (parsing strictly for validation) or as `"ab\"c"`, but it seems you want `"ab\\\"c"`, which doesn't seem so obviously useful.

Comment: @dfeuer No particular reason, was just playing around with Parsec.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

This is what I would do:

```
escape :: Parser String
escape = do
    d <- char '\\'
    c <- oneOf "\\\"0nrvtbf" -- all the characters which can be escaped
    return [d, c]

nonEscape :: Parser Char
nonEscape = noneOf "\\\"\0\n\r\v\t\b\f"

character :: Parser String
character = fmap return nonEscape <|> escape

parseString :: Parser String
parseString = do
    char '"'
    strings <- many character
    char '"'
    return $ concat strings
```

Now all you need to do is call it:

```
parse parseString "test" "\"this is \\\"test \\\" message \\\"sample\\\" text\""
```

Parser combinators are a bit difficult to understand at first, but once you get the hang of it they are easier than writing BNF grammars.

Comment: Shouldn't `nonEscape` be just `noneOf "\\\""`, to allow special characters to appear literally while likely speeding up processing considerably?

Comment: @dfeuer I think he just included some extra characters to demonstrate it, in case I wanted to add them. :)

Comment: @Sibi, my point was that it might be better to put the extra escapes into the definition of `escape` *without* excluding them from `nonEscape`. The only things that obviously *must* be excluded by `nonEscape` are `'\"'` and `'\\'`.

Comment: @dfeuer Out of the 7 special characters (i.e. `[0nrvtbf]`) the null character cannot be normally typed on the keyboard. It has to be copy pasted. The newline characters `\n` and `\r` are not allowed in Haskell strings (or for that matter most programming languages). Some languages like JavaScript allow newlines to be escaped but not Haskell. Vertical tab and form feed are hardly ever used in programming. Whitespace (except for space and newline) should never go unnoticed. This is reason enough to disallow all these special characters as literals in strings. It also serves as a good explanation

Comment: Because of the way parser combinators are implemented it doesn't make a difference whether `noneEscape = "\\\"\0\n\r\v\t\b\f"` or `nonEscape = "\\\""`. It will still take the same amount of time. This is because parsers are implemented using an array of lookup tables which determine the next state of the parser. Think of deterministic pushdown automata. For a given state you have a vector mapping each input symbol to a new state. Hence no matter what the input symbol, it only takes one lookup to get to the new state. The `noneOf` combinator produces a parser which is only one level deep. Fast.

Comment: @AaditMShah, now I understand.

Comment: @AaditMShah Why is it is like this `c <- oneOf "\\\"0nrvtbf"` ? Shouldn't it be like this: `c <- oneOf "\\\"\0\n\r\v\t\b\f"` in `escape` function ?

Comment: @Sibi No. An escape character consists of two characters - the backslash and (usually) a print character. For example to put a newline we type backslash followed by an `n` (i.e. `'\n'`). We don't type backslash followed by an actual newline (i.e. `'\<newline>'`). Hence we write `c <- oneOf "\\\"0nrvtbf"` and not `c <- oneOf "\\\"\0\n\r\v\t\b\f"`. Remember, we already matched the backslash using `d <- char '\\'`. Hope that helps.

Comment: @AaditMShah Thanks, should have noticed that we already matched the backlash.

Answer (score 3):

```
quotedString = do
    char '"'
    x <- many (noneOf "\"" <|> (char '\\' >> char '\"'))
    char '"'
    return x
```

I believe, this should work.

Comment: This will include \ in the result. `"\"" will be parsed to `\"` not `"`.

Comment: @Banthar, that seems to be the OP's intention. The code does not, however, seem to be as flexible as that in Aadit M. Shah's answer, and it looks like it would be hard to extend it to support escaping backslashes.

Answer (score 3):

In case somebody is looking for a more out of the box solution, [this answer in code-review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/105643/114790) provides just that. Here is a complete example with the right imports:

```
import           Text.Parsec
import           Text.Parsec.Language
import           Text.Parsec.Token

lexer :: GenTokenParser String u Identity
lexer = makeTokenParser haskellDef

strParser :: Parser String
strParser = stringLiteral lexer

parseString :: String -> Either ParseError String
parseString = parse strParser ""
```

Answer (score 1):

I prefer the following because it is easier to read:

```
quotedString :: Parser String
quotedString = do
    a <- string "\""
    b <- concat <$> many quotedChar
    c <- string "\""
    -- return (a ++ b ++ c) -- if you want to preserve the quotes
    return b
    where quotedChar = try (string "\\\\")
                   <|> try (string "\\\"")
                   <|> ((noneOf "\"\n") >>= \x -> return [x] )
```

Aadit's solution may be faster because it does not use `try` but it's probably harder to read.

Note that it is different from Aadit's solution. My solution ignores escaped things in the string and really only cares about `\"` and `\\`.

For example, let's assume you have a tab character in the string. 
My solution successfully parses `"\"\t\""` to `Right "\t"`. Aadit's solutions says `unexpected "\t"` `expecting "\\" or "\""`.

Also note that Aadit's solution only accepts 'valid' escapes. For example, it rejects `"\"\\a\""`. `\a` is not a valid escape sequence (well according to `man ascii`, it represents the system bell and is valid). My solution just returns `Right "\\a"`.

So we have two different use cases.

- My solution: Parse quoted strings with possibly escaped quotes and escaped escapes
- Aadit's solution: Parse quoted strings with valid escape sequences where valid escapes means `"\\\"\0\n\r\v\t\b\f"`

Answer (score 1):

I wanted to parse quoted strings and remove any backslashes used for escaping during the parsing step.  In my simple language, the only escapable characters were double quotes and backslashes.  Here is my solution:

```
quotedString = do
  string <- between (char '"') (char '"') (many quotedStringChar)
  return string
  where
    quotedStringChar = escapedChar <|> normalChar
    escapedChar = (char '\\') *> (oneOf ['\\', '"'])
    normalChar = noneOf "\""
```

Comment: "do  x <- foobar ;   return x" is the same as just "foobar"

Answer (score 0):

elaborating on @Priyatham response

```hs
pEscString::Char->Parser String
pEscString e= do
  char e;
  s<-many (
    do{char '\\';c<-anyChar;return ['\\',c]}
    <|>many1 (noneOf (e:"\\")))
  char e
  return$concat s
```